# Notepad++ Previous/Next history

Tags: notepad++

Does Notepad ++ offer the same feature of previous/next page as found in Adobe Reader?

For example, if I have two files opened named a.txt and b.txt:

1. First I view a.txt line 10.
2. Then I view b.txt at line 20 and then line 30
3. If I have a *previous page* function, clicking it once will go to b.txt line 20 and clicking it again will go to a.txt line 10

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this plugin called [Location Navigate](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/location-navigate-record-cursor-positions-navigate-between-them-notepad/)